# How to get k cluster mean for a given data based on a condition?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn, k-means

I have a csv file which contains date and mse (mean square error) values shown below.

```
date                       mse                                                  
2018-02-11                 14.34
2018-02-12                 7.24
2018-02-13                 4.5
2018-02-14                 3.5
2018-02-16                 12.67
2018-02-21                 45.66
2018-02-22                 15.33
2018-02-24                 98.44
2018-02-26                 23.55
2018-02-27                 45.12
2018-02-28                 78.44
2018-03-01                 34.11
2018-03-05                 23.33
2018-03-06                 7.45
...                        ...
```

Now I want to get two clusters for the `mse` values lesser than a certain limit say **40** so that I know what values lies to which cluster and their mean.

Now it usually needs two parameters or set of values.Since I am just concerned about the `mse` values and a cluster around it, I pass the other parameter as range of values of same size.This is what I did

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

df = pd.read_csv("mse_test.csv", parse_dates=["date"])

# get mse values lesser than 40
f1 = df[df['mse'] < 40].values
# get another list of equal size
f2 = list(range(0, 32))  # 32 is no of mse values below 40
X = np.array(list(zip(f1, f2)))
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(X)

labels = kmeans.predict(X)
# Centroid values
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=labels)
ax.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1], marker='*', c='#050505', s=1000)
plt.title('K Mean Classification')
plt.show()
```

But I get an error like below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/souvik/PycharmProjects/Pandas/test.py", line 21, in <module>
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(X)
  File "/home/souvik/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py", line 887, in fit
    X = self._check_fit_data(X)
  File "/home/souvik/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py", line 858, in _check_fit_data
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr', dtype=[np.float64, np.float32])
  File "/home/souvik/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 433, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

What am I doing wrong?

By the way, is there any way to get 2D plot instead of 3D plot?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply KMeans directly to your dataframe after filtering it by a specific condition.

In your case, you can use:

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(df.query('mse < 40'))
```

Comment: but then its affecting the subsequent lines for example `labels = kmeans.predict(X)`.What do I put in place of X now?

Comment: You can extract the dataframe you want and then act on it

df_train = df.query('mse < 40')
kmeans = Kmeans(n_clusters=2).fit(df_train)
labels = kmeans.predict(df_train)